# After chaning child in FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID), it's still listening previous child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If i change child in FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userID"), why it is still keep listening previous childs. Let say i have user1, user2 and user3. If i logIn with user1, it is listening only user1 values, after i logIn with user2, it is listening user1 and user2 values and if i logIn with user3, it is listening user1, user2, and user3 values. Why firebase keeps listening previous childs. If i logIn first time with user1, it dosent listening user2 and user3 values.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);

     databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID);
     databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: A `ChildEventListener` remains active until it is removed ([docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners)).  Are you removing the listener when it is no longer needed, for example in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Yep, now its working.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference of the `ChildEventListener` you're adding to your databaseReference, and then call

`if (childEventListener != null)
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(childEventListener);`

on the `onStop()` method of your activity.